# Analytic vectors and Taylor expansion

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

I was reading Reed & Simon where the following definition of an analytic vector is given.

**Definition:** Let $A$ be an operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. The set $C^{\infty}(A) := \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}D(A^{n})$ is called the $C^{\infty}$-vectors for $A$. A vector $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(A)$ is called an analytic vector for $A$ if:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\|A^{n}\varphi\|}{n!}t^{n} < \infty$$
for some $t > 0$.

Note that, in the above definition, the operator $A$ need not to be bounded or self-adjoint.

My question is very simple: suppose $\varphi$ is an analytic vector for $A$, for some $t>0$. Does it imply that relation:
$$e^{tA}\varphi = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(tA)^{n}}{n!}\varphi$$
hold? In other words, to evaluate $e^{tA}$ at $\varphi$ one simply Taylor expands $e^{tA}$? This is getting me a bit confused because of the following points:

- It *seems* that this is the whole point of the definition, however Reed & Simon don't explicitly state this (as far as I remember), which made me think it might not be true then.
- Moreover, if $A$ is self-adjoint operator then $e^{tA}$ is defined by the Spectral Theorem, and this Taylor expansion might be equivalent to the application $e^{tA}\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is analytic and $e^{tA}$ is given by the Spectral Theorem. However, if $A$ is *not* self-adjoint, then what does $e^{tA}$ even mean in the first place? Should I just *define* its application at analytic vectors by its Taylor expansion?

Comment: There could be too few analytic vectors to define $e^{tA}$ unambiguously using only analytic vectors in general case. When it is proved for self-adjoint operators that there is dense set of analytic vectors, one can make connection between "intuitive" definition using analytic vectors and definition using spectral theorem, for example, compare 2 definition, etc.

Comment: What definition are you using for $e^{tA}$, if not that Taylor series?